# What is the geometric meaning that the directional derivative is positive?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

We have the function $$f(x,y)=x^2y+xy^2+\frac{1}{3}y^3-4y$$ I have calculated the gradient $$\nabla f=\binom{2xy+y^2}{x^2+2xy+y^2-4}$$ The directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(1,1)$ at the direction $v=\binom{2}{1}$ is equal to $\frac{6}{\sqrt{5}}>0$.

What is the geometric meaning that the directional derivative is positive?

Comment: $f$ is increasing in that direction.

Comment: So $f$ is increasing in the point $(1,1)$ to the direction $v$ or how is the vector $v$ related to the sign? @CharlesHudgins

Comment: Imagine $f(x,y)$ is the elevation at $(x,y)$. If you stand at $(1,1)$ and walk in the direction $(2,1)^T$, you will go uphill.

Comment: I see! Thank you!! :-) @CharlesHudgins